# How to use Angular.Js on page postback in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

If using Angular.js what hapen when the page is postback.How Angular works when page is postback on server.

Comment: use ajax to avoid postback when using angular. fresh angular gets reloaded on post back. so you can not maintain any states.

Comment: if you want a postback and maintain the state then pass the all angular state variables to the server and re initialize when angular loads again.

Comment: thanks for help!.Any Sample code example to refer using AngularJs with page postback in asp.net will be more helpful